# How to launch a Web-Site? What are the steps?

Tags: rest, web, web-applications, xss, launch

If I wanna create a web-site (forum-social...) what are the steps to do?
After developed the app (html + js + nodejs) i've to buy a domain? How many it costs? And for the DB? What are the solutions? Why for example phpmyadmin can't be used for a web-site? For the sicurity instead? Should I buy an autentication-server or is sufficiently encript the data of the user?
I'd like to know how it all starts.
Thank you everyone!

Comment: How to create a website: https://websitesetup.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking stuff like this up before posting about it on StackOverflow, S/O is mainly used for specific questions/clarifications which the general tutorials can't help out with. However, this is something I struggled with back when I was figuring deployment stuff out myself, so I'll try and point you in the right direction:

1. You don't necessarily need a domain. It's useful if you're launching a product/company and need a presence on the Internet, but for displaying personal projects and other casual stuff, you can probably skip a domain purchase, since it has a recurring cost
2. Once you have (or don't have) a domain, what you **really** need is a place to host your web content. I would recommend [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deployment) to someone who's looking to try stuff out for the first time, they have a pretty straightforward setup process, and even let you commission databases services, etc from within the Heroku web app. There are also a ton of Heroku tutorials out there, and I've personally deployed a bunch of NodeJS web apps using Heroku, it's a pretty straightforward process. I've never really used phpMyAdmin, but Heroku's free and you don't even need to buy a domain to get started (you can just use a Heroku subdomain like the [Heroku test deployment](http://test.herokuapp.com/)) which will minimize your costs
3. Authentication is a whole other ballgame, but I would check out [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-how-to-handle-authentication-with-node-using-passport-js-4a56ed18e81e/) which I feel is pretty comprehensive, and should give you a good start.

Good luck!